# Why does a wave reflect on the edge of an open tube?

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection, boundary-conditions

Why does a wave reflect on the edge of an open tube? There is nothing solid to make the wave bounce.

Then why is it reflected?

Comment: The answer in this question is pretty good and answers your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38548/

Answer (score 0):

The boundary condition is that the sound pressure is zero there.

Comment: Is pressure zero? what do you mean...

Comment: The pressure there is given by the ambient pressure (for example 1 atm). This gives that the _sound_ pressure is (almost) zero there, much smaller than inside the tube. So for the sound pressure, this is a fixed end.

Comment: @Pieter The pressure **variation** about atmospheric pressure is zero.