# Standing waves in an open tube

Tags: waves

I've been asked a question by a student - it's off the beaten track, and I am struggling to get a definitive answer, even off other physics teachers...

If we have an open tube, so open at both ends, how can we end up with a standing wave being formed in this tube?

How can the initial wave reflect back and cause the formation of a standing wave?

I have my own ideas - but i am never happy with going with what i think, i always try and get the idea validated and hopefully approved!

Cheers,

Marc'

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38548/reflection-of-sound-waves-from-the-open-end-of-an-organ-pipe-relationship-b-w

Comment: Thank you so much for you help - it pretty much is in agreement with what i thought, but that answer is much more eloquently put! 

Thank you!